# postgresql group by datetime in join query

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have 2 tables in my postgresql timescaledb database (version 12.06) that I try to query through inner join.
Tables' structure:

```
CREATE TABLE currency(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    quote_asset TEXT
); 

CREATE TABLE currency_price (
    currency_id integer NOT NULL,
    dt timestamp WITHOUT time ZONE NOT NULL,
    open NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    high NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    low NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    close NUMERIC,
    volume NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        currency_id,
        dt
    ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_currency FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES currency(id)
);
```

The query I'm trying to make is:

```
SELECT currency_id AS id, symbol, MAX(close) AS close, DATE(dt) AS date
FROM currency_price
JOIN currency ON
currency.id = currency_price.currency_id
GROUP BY currency_id, symbol, date
LIMIT 100;
```

Basically, it returns all the rows that exist in currency_price table. I know that postgres doesn't allow select columns without an aggregate function or including them in "group by" clause. So, if I don't include dt column in my select query, i receive expected results, but if I include it, the output shows rows of every single day of each currency while I only want to have the max value of every currency and filter them out based on various dates afterwards.

I'm very inexperienced with SQL in general.
Any suggestions to solve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: hey there. could you add a few data sample? preferably in a fiddle

Comment: I don't get the last bit, you want to get max(close) value and date when was the maximum, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It shows every row instead. Still trying to create some sample data on fiddle.

Comment: I might recommend using the first/last functions something like this: https://youtu.be/okB3tcXsQB0 & https://youtu.be/w5dbC_iM4oE

Comment: Link to sample data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0455a/17 @Jim
Not sure if this is how it's supposed to work, but it seems to not persist any data, so I wrote all the queries one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, easiest one comes to mind is using window functions.

```
select * 
  from (
     SELECT currency_id,symbol,close,dt
           ,row_number() over(partition by currency_id,symbol
                                  order by close desc,dt desc) as rr
       FROM currency_price
       JOIN currency ON currency.id = currency_price.currency_id
      where dt::date = '2021-06-07'
       )q1 
 where rr=1
```

General window functions:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-window.html
works also with standard aggregate functions like SUM,AVG,MAX,MIN and others.

Some examples: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/

Comment: Yes, this does seem to work, although, I would need a query that would allow me to check for price peaks within a date that I indicate myself. I tried to tweak the query you gave, but I'm not very familiar with window functions, so, it didn't show what I was expecting. the last query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0455a/25 shows no results.

Comment: Oh, this works just as I need! Thanks a lot for looking into this and helping out.
@LongBeard_Boldy, would you be so kind to provide some link to where I could learn more about window functions? Seems to be a great means of querying data.